# Weird Laravel/Xampp behavior upon accessing old and newly uploaded file

Tags: laravel, flutter, xampp

I'm accessing an image with this :

```
http://MyServerIP/storage/motorcycle/Image.jpg
```

if the image is **already inside** the project directory **before** XAMPP installed, it works!

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\m2mobileapp-backend\storage\app\public\motorcycle
```

But when the image is uploaded from my Flutter app via Laravel to save it locally to my server **after installing XAMPP**, the uploaded image can not be accessed it's always ended with 404 | Not Found Laravel page.
I've make sure that the image directory, image name & extension, and the URL is all correct.
and that newly uploaded image is really exist on my server folder :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\m2mobileapp-backend\storage\app\public\motorcycle
```

that newly uploaded image can be accessed if i'm reinstalling XAMPP.
But it's different when i'm using my local IP PC address the newly uploaded file can be accessed right away after i uploaded it.

do u guys know why? i'm sorry i'm still new my words might be wrong but i hope u guys understand my English.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st try this : `php artisan serve --host [YourIP] --port 80`
then Restart Apache/XAMPP

if it's still not works, uninstall XAMPP and switch to Laragon.

If u're facing issues with Laragon about "QueryException, could not find driver"

U can follow these steps below :

1. Make sure u're editing the right php.ini, because sometimes laragon is directing you to the wrong php.ini
2. To locate the find the correct php.ini use "php --ini" on cmd.
3. After u find and open the correct php.ini uncomment:
   extension=pdo_mysql

I don't know why it works, i'm still new on Laravel and programming
would love if someone can explain why. It left me curious as the solution is just randomly happened why i try various of things hahah

Answer (score -2):

Laravel's storage:link command creates a symbolic link from the public/storage directory to the storage/app/public directory. This is often used to make files in the storage/app/public directory accessible from the web.

Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and potentially solve the issue:

Create Symbolic Link:

Ensure that the symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public is created. Run the following command in your Laravel project root directory:

php artisan storage:link

This command should create a symbolic link in the public directory named storage, pointing to storage/app/public.

Check File Permissions:

Ensure that the storage and public/storage directories have the correct permissions for the web server to read files. You can set the permissions using:

chmod -R 775 storage

Comment: Did AI write that answer? fyi: [Why can't I use Artificial Intelligence tools to generate answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy)

Comment: i've already run the command for the symbolic link before , thankyou for the answer

Comment: @brombeer I don't think it makes sense. If you have AI skills then you should use it. AI will give you an idea but you have to implement it. Development is all about R&D.

Comment: Doesn't really matter what you think about the topic, these are the site rules you should follow. I won't discuss in more detail, you can read the link I posted

Comment: AI can also produce wrong results. Why do you or your AI think `chmod -R 775 storage` would work on a Windows system?

Comment: That is why I told you If a person is good and experienced he can understand or use AI. It is not everyone's pocket. I think you should claim AI for generating the wrong info!! Maybe they are going to listen to you and eliminate the AI services.